# MySQL: aggregate data from distinct rows into other distinct rows?

Tags: mysql, distinct, aggregate-functions

I know the title is an abomination, but I can't think of a succinct way to describe my problem.

I have a table called `onsite_notes`.  `onsite_notes`'s PK is a field called `onsite_note_id`.  I'm trying to get all of the notes' time added up for each customer.  Currently, my query is returning double entries for some rows.  I'm not sure why, but it's really annoying.  What I want to do is count distinct rows that have a specific FK (customer_id).  Here's the current query.

```
SELECT c.searchable_name, co.*, sum(n.time) 
        as worked_hours_onsite, 'onsite' as type 
            FROM customers c 
              LEFT JOIN contracts co on c.customer_id = co.customer_id 
              LEFT JOIN onsite_tickets t ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id 
              LEFT JOIN onsite_notes n ON t.onsite_id = n.onsite_id 
                      and (n.date >= 1464760800) 
                      and (n.date < 1467352800) 
                      and (n.isbillable = 1) 
           WHERE co.contract_type != '' AND 
               ((timestamp(now()) between co.start_date and co.end_date) 
            OR ((timestamp(now()) <= co.end_date) AND (co.start_date = 0)) 
            OR ((timestamp(now()) >= co.start_date) AND (co.end_date = 0)) 
            OR ((co.start_date = 0) AND (co.end_date=0))) 
           GROUP BY c.customer_id DESC ) ....
```

That's the general idea of the thing.  It's got a unioned bit, but it's giving me the same headache.  Basically, how can I ensure that I'm getting unique rows for each customer?  My customer rows are unique, but the aggregated data isn't unique and I *want* it unique.

Comment: One of the table you're joining with has two rows for each customer ID, so that's doubling the rows when you join with `onsite_notes`. Can you show some sample data that produces the undesirable results?

Comment: Funny story. So, I had a co-worker look at it who is significantly more skilled and knowledgeable than myself. The SQL actually works given that the data in the table itself is correct. You are 100% correct. The problem is the rows were nonunique in a way. We ended up getting everything sorted out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sum you need a proper group by based ond the row you want grouped and if you have selected column you must adeguate the group by to the row you want selected

.. If you need distinct don't use group by

and last group by don't need  desc  .. desc i for order  by so the query should be  somethings like this

```
 SELECT c.searchable_name, co.*, sum(n.time) 
    as worked_hours_onsite, 'onsite' as type 
        FROM customers c 
          LEFT JOIN contracts co on c.customer_id = co.customer_id 
          LEFT JOIN onsite_tickets t ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id 
          LEFT JOIN onsite_notes n ON t.onsite_id = n.onsite_id 
                  and (n.date >= 1464760800) 
                  and (n.date < 1467352800) 
                  and (n.isbillable = 1) 
       WHERE co.contract_type != '' AND 
           ((timestamp(now()) between co.start_date and co.end_date) 
        OR ((timestamp(now()) <= co.end_date) AND (co.start_date = 0)) 
        OR ((timestamp(now()) >= co.start_date) AND (co.end_date = 0)) 
        OR ((co.start_date = 0) AND (co.end_date=0))) 
       GROUP BY c.searchable_name, co.*
```

Comment: The group is proper.  It's on the customer_id, which is how my data is ordered.  The problem is I need to get distinct data within that subset of data.